# Facing deadlock issue when rows accessed are different

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, deadlock

```
select  r.*
    from  reservations r
    where  r.workspaceSid = 'WS0c9faa70166e42f4cf3a8df4b11b4d73'
      and  r.workerSid = 'WK89d7521c91805d7f0a8a2d38a6ec7ab4'
      and  r.status IN (0, 6) for update
```

2023-03-22T10:35:38.458591Z 33536411 [Note] InnoDB: *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

RECORD LOCKS space id 474931 page no 14657 n bits 416 index fk_workspace_sid of table `twilio_wds`.`reservations` trx id 68165090733 lock_mode X waiting
2023-03-22T10:35:38.458616Z 33536411 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) TRANSACTION:

TRANSACTION 68165090729, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
89 lock struct(s), heap size 8400, 170 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 33536411, OS thread handle 139955900372736, query id 47887747705 172.25.89.40 twilio Sending data

```
select  r.*
    from  reservations r
    where  r.workspaceSid = 'WS0c9faa70166e42f4cf3a8df4b11b4d73'
      and  r.workerSid = 'WK53a59d20955be23871feb083639ecd30'
      and  r.status IN (0, 6) for 
update
```

2023-03-22T10:35:38.458647Z 33536411 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):

RECORD LOCKS space id 474931 page no 14657 n bits 416 index fk_workspace_sid of table `twilio_wds`.`reservations` trx id 68165090729 lock_mode X
2023-03-22T10:35:38.458665Z 33536411 [Note] InnoDB: *** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:

This is the innodb status page deadlock result.  The rows accessed in these transactions are different and hence there should be no contention that could cause deadlock right?

I tried to understand the rows affected and the rows were different.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE reservations`.

Answer (score 0):

This composite index may help:

```
INDEX(workspaceSid, workerId, status)
```

In any case, your app must plan for a Deadlock.  The usual code is to catch it and replay the entire transaction.